# Reactor flux stop and unsubscribe after 1 event received

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I have the following problem: i built a client reactor.core.publisher.Flux using Spring to listen for SSEs that waits for some events and if it dosen't get them after 15 seconds(timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(15))) it will do something else. However, i would like the flux to stop and to unsubscribe the consumer if an event was received in the first 15 seconds.
Here is some code:

```
flux = webClient.get()
                .uri(URI)
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<Foo>>() {})
                .timeout(ofSeconds(15));
        eventStream.doOnError(e -> {
            logger.info("No event was received in 15 seconds!");
        }).subscribe(new CustomConsumer(reporter));
```

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly what the `take` operator does:

```
.bodyToFlux(String.class)
.take(1)
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that blockFirst(Duration duration) is the answer in my case because it waits for some time and after that it throws a timeout.

Comment: throwing is for blocking imperative code, so this is best avoided in any webflux application

Comment: i disagree because this is blocking for a period of time, if it was like you say then this function wouldn't be there available

Comment: any amount of blocking inside a reactive stack is dangerous if you don't take extra steps to ensure the blocking code is executing in a suitable thread (or rather a `Scheduler`), because it *will* impact processing of unrelated requests. "this function wouldn't be there available" => it is there for the small percentage of cases where you want to go from reactive to imperative, mainly inside of unit tests (although we recommend using `StepVerifier` instead) or the `main` block of toy applications